# COLUMN AMBIGUOUSLY DEFINED ORACLE

Tags: oracle

im getting an column ambiguously defined im trying to write a query to get data from three different tables my query is

```
select flight_no,
       country_code,
       destination,
       depatue_time,
       arrival_time 
from flight,
     country,
     flight_availibility 
where country_code='MCT'
  and destination='IND' 
order by flight_no;
```

and im getting error can anybody tell me what is wrong!!!

Comment: (1) Never use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit, proper, modern `JOIN` syntax.  (2) Always qualify your column names (preferably with table aliases), especially if you are learning SQL.  (3) The error is pretty obvious; a column that you have referred to is in more than one table.

Comment: You are joining 3 tables with no join conditions. Is this right?

Comment: Please edit you question using the `edit` button immediately below the tags and include the definitions of each of the tables involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you're asking for a column that shares a name from more than one of those tables. You want 'flight_no' - but, there may be a column named 'flight_no' in both the flight and country tables.

To avoid this, use aliases in your FROM clause.

Example

```
select a.col1, b.col1
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.id;
```

This isn't ambiguous, because you're explicitly telling Oracle which columns named 'col1' you want - you're not making it guess.

This isn't part of your question, but your query as you write it will cause the database to join every record in each table to every other record in the other two tables. This is known as a Cartesian Join or Product.

Is it necessarily wrong? Maybe not. But 99% of the time, it's not what you want. You only want the rows that 'match' - so use a WHERE clause and filter out the rows.

Or go the ANSI JOIN way and do it in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because same column name having in the 2 tables , so when we run the query using only column name , this error is occurring

Try the below to avoid those issue :

```
select a.flight_no,b.country_code,a.destination,c.depature_time,c.arrival_time
```

from 
   flight a ,
    country b